# Selecting same value from two columns in a lookup table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table as follows

```
UserID  CONSUMERID
1          2
1          3
1          4
5          1
```

this is a lookup column, user can be consumer here.
I need to query the table and get a single column output so that for example if ID = 1 I should be able to query userid and get all consumnerid data where userid = 1 and at the same time query get all userid data where consumerid = 1.. all the results should come in one column. So in other words query both columns for 1 and return opposite column value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION`(implicit DISTINCT) or `UNION ALL`, like so:

```
SELECT UserId FROM table WHERE ConsumerId = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ConsumerId FROM table WHERE UserID = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b41e4/1)

Comment: I think it's correct, but in first query it should be `WHERE ConsumerId = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without the union, just using logic:

```
select (case when UserId = 1 then Consumerid else UserId end) as id
from t
where UserId = 1 or ConsumerId = 1
```